# top of Swift custom font clipping

Tags: swift, swiftui, clipping, custom-font, embedded-fonts

I have a custom font in my app, I added it to the app properly, I set up the Target Membership, added it to the plist file, etc, everything is fine and the I can use the font, but the top of some characters are clipped:

[image: Top of the 1st line gets clipped]

As you can see it only happens in the 1st line, and it only happens with these characters, the rest is OK.

When I select it in the canvas, then it's pretty clear that the top is getting clipped, but adjusting the frame doesn't change this and that's not an option most of the time anyway.

[image: Frame in canvas]

Any solution for this? Has anyone else seen this problem before? Is this Swift or SwiftUI related, or there is a problem with the font?

The code itself is super simple:

```
import SwiftUI

    struct ContentView: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            
            Text("CSOQG-098632 CSOQG-098632")
                .font(.custom("Lausanne-500", size: 44))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you show your code for this?

Comment: just edited the original question

Comment: If you control the font, make sure the font metrics are correct. `Text` cannot handle fonts that draw significantly outside of their nominal metrics (I haven't nailed down exactly which metric it uses, though). I've opened two FBs about this (FB7545192 "Text clips Zapfino" and FB7497447 "Text clips extreme diacritics ("zalgo")"), but Apple has so far ignored my reports for a year.

Comment: In your case, the clipping is on glyphs that draw above the cap-height (which is completely normal for glyphs that have a curve at the top). My guess is that your ascent equals your cap height, and you need to increase your ascent to match your actual tallest glyph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like font baseline problem. As workaround you can compensate it like

```
Text("CSOQG-098632 CSOQG-098632")
    .font(.custom("Lausanne-500", size: 44))
    .baselineOffset(-10)                      // << tune here !!
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it, only needed a tiny offset luckily!